# Alternative to textit in LaTeX

Tags: italic

I have one text that need to be italicized.

```
   \textit{some text2 ~\\ some text2}
```

But i found `~\\` converted to `\newline\`. Is there any alternative to `\textit`? Is there any alternative to `\it`?

Comment: Not sure I understand your motivations, but anyway you entered \\, which is the same as `\newline` in this context.

Comment: Your issue does not seem to be related to the italics command. It is more about how you are using '~' and `\\ `.

Comment: I just graded 20 LaTeX assignments and usually students use `\textit` when they really need `\emph`. Why do you want to typeset text in italics?

Comment: I do not understand the problem.  The result of your snippet looks like what I would expect.  What do *you* expect (or desire) the output of this code snippet to look like?

Comment: I just need to italicize the character.

Comment: @manish They mean “what do you want with ``~\\``”, obviously, all the text inside `\textit{…}` will be italicized. By the way, I would normally use `\emph` instead of `\textit` as Marc van Dongen said.

Comment: Do you perhaps assume that `\\` should provide you with the character that `\textbackslash` would offer?

Answer (score 6):

I assume your intent was to get a backslash, instead of a `\newline` which is what `\\` is. In that case you can use `\textbackslash` with either the macro `\textit{...}`, or the font switch `{\itshape ...}` as in the first two lines below:

[image]

The third line above was produced with `\emph{...}` and yields identical results (in *this* case).

However, you should carefully consider why you are doing this. Do you want an italic font, or are you trying to emphasize some words? In most cases one is trying to emphasize some words in which case `\emph{...}` should be used. Note the differences in the following where we have nested uses of `\textit{...}`, `{\itshape ...}`, and `\emph{...}`:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `{` and `}` when using the switch `\itshape` is so that the italics font switch is only on during within a scope.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \textit{some text2 ~\textbackslash~ some text2}
    
    {\itshape some text2 ~\textbackslash~ some text2} 
    
    \emph{some text2 ~\textbackslash~ some text2} 


    \medskip

    \textit{textit text  containing \textit{textit text}}
    
    {\itshape itshape text  containing {\itshape itshape text}}
    
    \emph{emphasized text containing \emph{emphasized text}} 

\end{document}
```