# Warning/Error While using textit

Tags: italic

This refers to previous question.
   [Alternative to textit in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170700/alternative-to-textit-in-latex)

I am using textit for making text italic.

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a5paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\textit{\textbf{Some Text}~\\ 
 This gene encodes the pro-alpha1 chains of type III collagen.~\\ 
~\\  
SSS.~\\ 
~\\ 

ZZZZ in the ZZZ3A1 gene, which ZZZ type III pro-XXX, cause type IV SSS-Danlos   SSS, a rw rw to rw SSS in SSS rwr rw.}
\end{document}linecolor=goldenpoppy
```

I get following error message.

```
Runaway argument?
{\textbf {Some Text}~\\ This gene encodes the pro-alpha1 chains of ty\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.9 ...os   SSS, a rw rw to rw SSS in SSS rwr rw.}
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some reminders:

1. Don't use `~\\` while ending lines.
2. Don't use two `\\` to end a paragraph.
3. Use `\par` in place of all `~\\` and `~\\~\\` or leave a blank line.
4. If you are using italic shape for an entire paragraph, it is better to use `itshape` (which is a switch) inside a group → `{\itshape your text...}`.

Having said that, this works:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\begin{document}
{\itshape \textbf{Some Text}

 This gene encodes the pro-alpha1 chains of type III collagen.\par
SSS.\par
ZZZZ in the ZZZ3A1 gene, which ZZZ type III pro-XXX, cause type IV SSS-Danlos
   SSS, a rw rw to rw SSS in SSS rwr rw.}
\end{document}
```

[image]